# Unable to execute a simple query via elasticsearch-head

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to execute some query on elasticsearch using the plugin head and the web interface. But at the moment I have no result. It's just a simple query.

[image]

So it is what I type in the form. In fact it returns me all the contents of the indexed dataset. "Origin" is one of my fields and "ROA" a correct value.

Here is a part of the result :

```
{

    took: 531
    timed_out: false
    _shards: {
        total: 5
        successful: 5
        failed: 0
    }
    hits: {
        total: 47925065
        max_score: 1
        hits: [
            {
```

It should return me about 35 000 result.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok my bad I found the solution.

I had to set "Post" method isntead of "Get".

And the correct Json was :

```
{
  "query": {
       "match": {
           "Year": "1987"
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding this work around.  It isn't your bad though.  The search api should take a GET request, not a POST.  It is annoying that this tool has it wrong, but at least this workaround makes it usable.